# Mac: Why am I getting a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'"?

Tags: python, spring-boot, spacy

I'm using the Java exec() function to execute a python program within Springboot.

This approach works fine on Windows, but on the Mac, for Spacy, as an example, I get:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Both Python and Spacy are in the same bin folder.

I've tried all the suggestions I can find:

(At the command line)

1. pip install spacy  (also did to be sure pip3 install spacy)
2. python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

I've done these steps and all the libraries are already satisfied.

When running this service on Windows from Tomcat, it works.

When running this service on Mac from Tomcat, then I get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'"

--

Not sure what else to try.

Would appreciate any suggestions to help the code running inside SpringBoot to be able to find Spacy on the Mac.

This problem on the Mac isn't limited to Spacy. I had the same issue with Gensim so hopefully the same resolution, once found, will work with Gensim on the Mac, too.

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Comment: You probably have more than one Python installed and are using a different one than you think you are; unfortunately that can happen pretty easily in general, especially on Macs. Try running `import sys; print(sys.executable)` to check which binary is being used.

Comment: Thanks. Just one one Python version installed but somehow my SYSTEM PATH got messed up so trying to run the shell command in Java wasn't finding the Python packages. All fixed up now. Appreciate your suggestion.